# callback issue in Facebook while user clicks anywhere while Facebook login page is loading

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have one activity(Login) and one class(FacebookLogin).

```
public void loginWithFacebook(boolean fetchUserInfo) {

Log.d(TAG, "Logging into Facebook.");

String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(activity
        .getBaseContext());
mCurrentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity.getBaseContext())
            .setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "SESSION open");
}
mCurrentSession = Session.getActiveSession();

if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
    openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
    if (openRequest != null) {
        openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday",
                    "email", "user_hometown"));
            openRequest
                    .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);


    }
}
```

}

this is method of Facebook class. specified onActivityResult method in login activity. 
this works well , unless user clicks anywhere while Facebook login page is loading.
If user clicks anywhere it calls onActivityResult class.
why is this happening?

Comment: are you testing it on jellyBean?

Comment: testing in emulator for api level 17.

Comment: is progress dialog hides when you touch the screen?

Comment: if this problem only appears in API level 16 or 17 then you need to change only one progress dialog statement in facebook SDK library

Comment: tried only on api level 17. but if that's the problem what line i need to change?

Comment: please let me know, is Progress dialog dismisses when you click on any part of screen?

Comment: i have post my answer,have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `onCreate()`  method of `WebDialog.java` in FacebookSDK library, you will find following statement:

```
  spinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
```

add the below statement after it

```
spinner.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

you are ready to go!